# How to escape single quote in django form widget

Tags: django, django-forms, attributes, single-quotes

I am trying to set HTML `<input>` attribute through django ModelForm.
with the following code.

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {'product_image' :FileInput(attrs={'data-form-data':'{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'}),
                  }
```

what i am trying to get, is like this (notice single-quote after `data-form-data`)

```
<input type="file" name="product_name"
data-form-data='{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>
```

But i got this instead (notice double-quotes after `data-form-data`)

```
<input type="file" name="product_name"
data-form-data="{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}">
```

How can i prevent django to automatically convert single-quote to double-quotes ?
thank you in advance.

Comment: I wonder what's the use case for rendering the csrf_token to an html-attribute? Furthermore I'm not sure if this is possible. It would require the template engine to iteratively render the template: First the formfield rendering to `data-form-data='{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'`, then again rendering variable in there. Does the engine work that way?
 I don't know. I think you should review your software architecture. And btw shouldn't it be `{% csrf_token %}` instead of `{{ csrf_token }}`?

Comment: Hi thank you for commenting, actually, i got the code from here https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/22/django-multiple-file-upload-using-ajax.html

Comment: I think HTML rendering will work the way it is working for you, with the double quotes. Also, the token will not be replaced this way. Please explain why do you want to do that. You can try injecting the attribute through JS as well.